# Moving important opencart tables to another database

Tags: mysql, migration, opencart, database-migration

I'm working on merged system (Joomla + OC) and I need to "unmerge" it.

It is very unstable and I can't use any extensions for import export because of it.

What I'd like to do is to export all necessary tables so that users, orders, products, categories and languages are preserved.

I used to do this only for products and categories before but now users and their orders need to be preserved as well.

**It seems like I always miss to export something, so if anyone has minimal list of tables that need to be exported that would be very helpful**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to backup products,categories,customers and orders only or anything more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on what your site provides. i would copy anything that has a to to it for example product_to_category of course your products table category table customers table, manufacturers if you use them. orders inf you need any history. you know your website better than anyone if it was me i would export everything and then delete anything that i dont need.